# Azure Synapse is failing to perform the deployment giving error "type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlDwDatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid"

Tags: sql, azure-synapse, dacpac

I am working on Azure Synapse. I am able to build the Azure Synapse project successfully using the Azure CI pipeline's MS Build task.

But as I am trying to deploy Azure Synapse using the Azure CD pipeline, I am getting the following error.

```
Internal Error. The database platform service with type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlDwDatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid. You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide the full type name of a valid database platform service.
```

I am deploying the DacPac using the following task. I hope this should not be any concern.

**https://github.com/DrJohnT/AzureDevOpsExtensionsForSqlServer/tree/master/extensions/PublishDacPac**

This is a weird error because a couple of days ago same deployment was done successfully.

Please help!

Comment: You might also report this here: https://github.com/DrJohnT/AzureDevOpsExtensionsForSqlServer/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. I have deeply investigated and found that this issue is related to Agent which I am using in the Azure DevOps pipeline.

One more thing, I am deploying SQL Database and Azure Synapse using different pipelines but using the same agent.

**Below screenshot of the Azure SQL database pipeline agent. SQL Database is deploying successfully with agent specification vs2017-win2016**
[image]

**Below screenshot of the Azure Synapse deployment pipeline agent. Azure Synapse is deploying successfully with agent specification windows-2019**

[image]

***The gist is that one agent is being used but the specification is different for the Azure Synapse and SQL database while both are building on VS2019.***